# LIRC Python client bindings

Tags: python, lirc

I am needing to use the LIRC Python client bindings for a project. The LIRC website has good documentation over them, but I have no idea how to actually get them besides copying and pasting the python code. It never says anywhere on the site that I have seen where to actually get them.

Where/how do I get these bindings?

http://www.lirc.org/html/lirc_client.html

http://www.lirc.org/api-docs/html/group__python__bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install [python-lirc](https://pypi.org/project/python-lirc/#description) or python3-lirc available on PyPi.

This is a Python binding to LIRC.

Comment: `python-lirc` is/was never the official LIRC Python client binding package. Meanwhile the python-lirc package is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the latest version available on the upstream site: http://sf.net/p/lirc. This is the version actually described in the docs. The pypi described in previous reply is another beast.

Comment: After I've installed LIRC, how do I access the Python module like it does in the documentation `import lirc`?

Comment: Depends on how you ran configure; with default options you should find the package in something like  /usr/local/share/lirc/python-pkg/. There you could find the README.rst for more info

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Raspbian you only need `lirc` package. It contains the lirc Python bindings package sources unpacked and as tar.gz file.

You can install the lirc Python bindings to a currently active venv is for example by this command:

```
pip3 install /usr/share/lirc/lirc-0.10.1.tar.gz
```

The command above works for Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm), for your Linux distribution and lirc version you may have to adapt it.

Test scripts for testing functionality of lirc python bindings:

```
import lirc
print(lirc.get_default_socket_path())
```

Outputs `/var/run/lirc/lircd`

```
with lirc.RawConnection('/var/run/lirc/lircd') as conn:
    press = conn.readline()
    print(press)
```

If you omit the parameter `'/var/run/lirc/lircd'` the default socket path printed by example 1 is used.

```
import lirc

with lirc.LircdConnection('mylirc') as conn:
    while True:
        string = conn.readline()
        print(string)
```

The `'mylirc'` argument is taken form `/etc/lirc/lircrc` where each key is defined. It is there defined as `prog = mylirc` in each begin/end block.